# Imageview above actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a imageview that i want to display above the actionbar.

I have been able to customize the actionbar's views that I have using actionbar sherlock, but i have not been able to add any view above the Actionbar view.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative layout set the background as desired of the action bar....
in the body of the relative layout add the other button/view

relative layout
   height
width
background

//body for views

close relative layout

Comment: How do i use relativelayout for actionbarsherlock?